# Maven giving error Compilation failure javac: invalid target release: 11

Tags: maven, maven-toolchains-plugin

I am trying to build a new dropwizard service. On running the `mvn clean install` I am getting the following error. This is a personal project . I have some official projects which need Maven to use JAVA 8 only. Hence I cannot change the JAVA_HOME to newer releases.

So mvn --version gives me this:

```bash
mvn --version          
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-25T00:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: /Users/nitinmisra/software/apache-maven-3.6.0
Java version: 1.8.0_401, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-1.8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.3", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

So for using JAVA-11 for the new project I am trying to configure toolchains. My pom looks like the following -:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>distribution-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>DropWizard</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <dropwizard.version>4.0.7</dropwizard.version>
        <mainClass>org.example.DistributionServiceApplication</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>toolchain</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <toolchains>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>11</version>
                            <vendor>sun</vendor>
                        </jdk>
                    </toolchains>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>java11+</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!--
                Workaround for "javadoc: error - The code being documented uses modules but the packages
                defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ are in the unnamed module."
                -->
                <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I have toolschains.xml in the .m2 folder in my home directory

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<toolchains>
  <!-- JDK toolchains -->
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>17</version>
      <vendor>sun</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>11</version>
      <vendor>sun</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.17.jdk</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
 
  <!-- other toolchains -->
  <toolchain>
    <type>netbeans</type>
    <provides>
      <version>5.5</version>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <installDir>/path/to/netbeans/5.5</installDir>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
</toolchains>%
```

I have tried to configure toolchains in my pom for getting this to work.

### Update:

---

I have installed maven to version 3.9.6 . But I am getting the following error.

```bash
distribution-service mvn clean install -X
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /Users/nitinmisra/software/apache-maven-3.9.6
Java version: 17.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.3", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.fillBuf (MXParser.java:3898)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.more (MXParser.java:3980)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseProlog (MXParser.java:1774)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl (MXParser.java:1757)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next (MXParser.java:1375)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.internal.extension.model.io.xpp3.CoreExtensionsXpp3Reader.read (CoreExtensionsXpp3Reader.java:586)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.internal.extension.model.io.xpp3.CoreExtensionsXpp3Reader.read (CoreExtensionsXpp3Reader.java:613)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.internal.extension.model.io.xpp3.CoreExtensionsXpp3Reader.read (CoreExtensionsXpp3Reader.java:628)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.internal.extension.model.io.xpp3.CoreExtensionsXpp3Reader.read (CoreExtensionsXpp3Reader.java:659)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.readCoreExtensionsDescriptor (MavenCli.java:770)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.loadCoreExtensions (MavenCli.java:713)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container (MavenCli.java:627)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:277)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
(base) ➜  distribution-service
```

Current state of pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>distribution-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>DropWizard</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <dropwizard.version>4.0.7</dropwizard.version>
        <mainClass>org.example.DistributionServiceApplication</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.12.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>toolchain</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <toolchains>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>11</version>
                            <vendor>sun</vendor>
                        </jdk>
                    </toolchains>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
<!--                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>-->
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>java11+</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>[11,)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!--
                Workaround for "javadoc: error - The code being documented uses modules but the packages
                defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ are in the unnamed module."
                -->
                <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: First why using old Maven version? Second Why defined an ancient old toolchain-plugin version?  (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) Why repeating maven-surefire-plugin? And also you have not corectly defined toolchain... please check this setup: https://github.com/khmarbaise/youtube-videos/tree/main/episode-toolchains also why not using JDK 11 with --release option? Maven-compiler-plugin configuration is also wrong... hard coded `<source>..</source>`... ?

Comment: Are you really sure you need toolchain setup? Use JDK 11 and produce Java 8 output? (You should take a look to up-to-date Maven version 3.9.6 current one https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html)

Comment: Also as already mentioned use https://sdkman.io/ to handle different JDK version on your Mac...

Comment: @khmarbaise is it okay to let maven use java 8 and through toolchains use java 11 for compiling the code. Can we have a lower version for maven and have newer versions defined in toolchains.

Comment: Do you have an `extentensions.xml` in your `.mvn` directory ? Have you upgraded the toolschain plugin version? You have not updated the configuration for toolchains correctly see my link to the git repository... (check that pom file)

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to take a look on [skdman](https://sdkman.io/). In my work I have project that use jdk8, there are some on jdk17 and one on jdk21, by running one command I just switch between version whenever I need, it's very handy and simple.

You can chose for example OpenJDK

```
sdk install java x.y.z-open
```

then

```
sdk use java x.y.z-open
```

Every time you run the command above, the $JAVA_HOME is updated to point to the current version of Java you decided to use.